# Subscribing to Service Fabric cluster level events

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am trying to create a service that will update an external list of Service Endpoints for applications running in my service fabric cluster.  (Basically I need to replicate the Azure Load Balancer in my on premises F5 Load Balancer.)

During last month's Service Fabric Q&A, the team pointed me at [RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.registerservicenotificationfilterasync).

I made a stateless service using this method, and deployed it to my development cluster.  I then made a new service by running the ASP.NET Core Stateless service template.

I expected that when I deployed the second service, the break point would hit in my first service, indicating that a service had been added.  But no breakpoint was hit.

I have found very little in the way of examples for this kind of thing on the internet, so I am asking here hopping that someone else has done this and can tell me where I went wrong.

Here is the code for my service that is trying to catch the application changes:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    var fabricClient = new FabricClient();

    long? filterId = null;


    try
    {
        var filterDescription = new ServiceNotificationFilterDescription
        {
            Name = new Uri("fabric:")
        };
        fabricClient.ServiceManager.ServiceNotificationFilterMatched += ServiceManager_ServiceNotificationFilterMatched;
        filterId = await fabricClient.ServiceManager.RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync(filterDescription);


        long iterations = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (filterId != null)
            await fabricClient.ServiceManager.UnregisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync(filterId.Value);
    }



}

private void ServiceManager_ServiceNotificationFilterMatched(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Change Occured");
}
```

If you have any tips on how to get this going, I would love to see them.

Comment: Not really related to your question but.. `Basically I need to replicate the Azure Load Balancer` - I'm not following what functionality is it you're trying to replicate here? From what I know ALB is pretty "dumb" and unaware of SF?

Comment: Can you try `Name = new Uri("fabric:/")`

Comment: @LoekD - I did it that way because of this post, where a Microsoft employee said to do it without the trailing slash.  https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/122  I did try it though, and I get "Invalid Name URI".

Comment: @Mardoxx - In June's Q&A with the Service Fabric team, they told me that the Azure Load Balancer handles updating pools when a node reboots.  I guess they could have been wrong.  But I need that functionality in my F5 either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [MatchNamePrefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/system.fabric.description.servicenotificationfilterdescription.matchnameprefix.aspx) to true, like this:

```
    var filterDescription = new ServiceNotificationFilterDescription
    {
        Name = new Uri("fabric:"),
        MatchNamePrefix = true
    };
```

otherwise it will only match specific services. In my application I can catch cluster wide events when this parameter is set to `true`.