# How to listen to the application deletion event in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am running a stateless service in Azure Service Fabric in the .NET Framework. I want to perform some clean up activities, and remove some configurations from the registry if all of my applications get deleted from a node in my Service Fabric Cluster. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by [registering notification callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.registerservicenotificationfilterasync). Register for all applications and services by using this code:

```
var filterDescription = new ServiceNotificationFilterDescription
{
    Name = new Uri("fabric:"),
    MatchNamePrefix = true
};
```

You interpret a notification with [no endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt124897(v=azure.100)) as a service deletion.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45247218/5946937) too.

Comment: Thank you @LoekD. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: How is this different from OnCloseAsync() event?. It is called when the service instance is going to be gracefully shut down.

Comment: The nuance is in 'when all my application gets deleted'; you'd need to know the state of multiple services.