# Blocking a Service Fabric service shutdown externally

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm going to write a quick little SF service to report endpoints from a service to a load balancer. That part is easy and well understood. FabricClient. Find Services. Discover endpoints. Do stuff with load balancer API.

But I'd like to be able to deal with a graceful drain and shutdown situation. Basically, catch and block the shutdown of a SF service until after my app has had a chance to drain connections to it from the pool.

There's no API I can find to accomplish this. But I kinda bet one of the services would let me do this. Resource manager. Cluster manager. Whatever.

Is anybody familiar with how to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know this isn't possible in a way you've described.

Service Fabric service can be shutdown by multiple reasons: re-balancing, errors, outage, upgrade etc. Depending on the type of service (stateful or stateless) they have slightly different shutdown routine (see [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle#stateless-service-startup)) but in general if the service `replica` is shutdown gracefully then `OnCloseAsync` method is invoked. Inside this method `replica` can perform a safe cleanup. There is also a second case - when replica is forcibly terminated. Then `OnAbort` method is called and there are no clear statements in documentation about guarantees you have inside `OnAbort` method.

Going back to your case I can suggest the following pattern:

1. When `replica` is going to shutdown inside `OnCloseAsync` or `OnAbort` it calls `lbservice` and reports that it is going to shutdown.
2. The `lbservice` the reconfigure load balancer to exclude this `replica` from request processing.
3. `replica` completes all already processing requests and shutdown.

Please note that you would need to implement startup mechanism too i.e. when `replica` is started then it reports to `lbservice` that it is active now.

In a mean time I like to notice that Service Fabric already implements this mechanics. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-api-management-overview) is an example of how **API Management** can be used with Service Fabric and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy) is an example of how **Reverse Proxy** can be used to access Service Fabric services from the outside.

---

**EDIT 2018-10-08**

In order to abstract receive notifications about services endpoints changes in general you can try to use [FabricClient.ServiceManagementClient.ServiceNotificationFilterMatched Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.servicenotificationfiltermatched?view=azure-dotnet).

There is a similar situation solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247218/subscribing-to-service-fabric-cluster-level-events).

Comment: Yeah. I need to be able to do it from outside the specific service though. Some are guest executables.

I'm running on prem, not Azure. I'm trying to duplicate whatever it is that's going on in Azure that drains the App GW or LB properly.

Comment: @wasabi correct me if I am wrong but are you saying that this service would act as GW or LB? Or this service is going to communicate with external LB or GW?

Comment: It's going to communicate with an external LB or GW. I want to make sure that LB has been drained before the service actually begins to stop.

Comment: @wasabi I have updated the answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like part of my problem. And a useful one at that. I think stalling the shutdown is still not answered, though, right?